# Configure Restangular to reuse it in any part of the app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I see in docs this code:

```
// First way of creating a Restangular object. Just saying the base URL
var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('accounts');

// This will query /accounts and return a promise.
baseAccounts.getList().then(function(accounts) {
  $scope.allAccounts = accounts;
});
```

What's the best practice to set that `baseAccounts` variable? Should I set it in every controller I need it to use in? Or should I put it like `$rootScope.baseAccounts = ...`?
I want to set it somewhere so that then to make queries from any part of my Angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a service which returns a singleton object that has all your rest configurations and inject that in the components which utilize rest:

```
angular.module("someApp")
.factory("REST", ["Restangular", function(Rest) {
    var Service = {};
    Service.Accounts = Rest.all("accounts");
    return Service;
}])
.controller("someController", ["$scope", "REST", function($scope, REST) {
    REST.Accounts.getList().then(function(accounts) {
        $scope.allAccounts = accounts;    
    }, function(error) { /* error handling */ });
}]);
```